# Does this set of functions separate points of $\Omega$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$$\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a open connected set (domain). Let $z\in\Omega$ I want to show that if all bounded holomorphic functions on $\Omega$ are not just the constant functions (denoted by $H^\infty(\Omega)\not\equiv\mathbb{C}$), then, for every $0\neq\xi\in\mathbb{C}$, there exists a bounded holomorphic function $f$ on $\Omega$ such that $f’(z)\xi\neq 0$

The proof goes like this (see [proof of Proposition 2.5.1 in this book](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Invariant_Distances_and_Metrics_in_Compl.html?id=rhLoBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y)).
Suppose $H^\infty(\Omega)\not\equiv\mathbb{C}$ and let $f_0\in H^\infty(\Omega), a_1,a_2\in\Omega$, such that $f_0(a_1)\neq f_0(a_2)$.

Define for $j=1,2$, $f_j$ as

\begin{equation*}
    f_j(z) = \begin{cases}
              \frac{f_0(z)-f_0(a_j)}{z-a_j}& \text{if } z\neq a_j,\\
               f_0’(a_j) & \text{if } z= a_j.
          \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Then it is said that $f_0,f_1,f_2$ separates points of $\Omega$. And $rank(f_0’,f_1’,f_2’)=1$ on $\Omega$ and hence proved.

I do not understand how $f_0,f_1,f_2$ separates points of $\Omega$? And what is the meaning of $rank(f_0’,f_1’,f_2’)=1$?

Answer (score 1):

The statement about separating points means that for any distinct $z,w \in \Omega$ there exist $j \in \{0,1,2\}$ with $f_j(z) \ne f_j(w)$, and the statement about the rank of the derivatives just means that these three derivatives do not simultaneously vanish at any point in $\Omega$. And since you are working in one complex dimension here, you don't need $\xi$, just need to show that given $z_0 \in \Omega$ (which you omitted from your assumptions, but this is the way it is phrased in the referenced book) there exists a bounded holomorphic function $f$ in $\Omega$ with $f'(z_0) \ne 0$.

I think there is a more elementary proof than the one in the book. By assumption there exists a non-constant function $f$ in $\Omega$. If $f'(z_0) \ne 0$, then you are done. Otherwise, the Taylor expansion at $z_0$ looks like $f(z) = w_0 + a_n (z-z_0)^n + \ldots$ with $w_0 = f(z_0)$ and $a_n \ne 0$ for some $n \ge 2$. Then $g(z) = \frac{f(z)-w_0}{(z-z_0)^{n-1}}$ is another bounded function in $\Omega$ (which is not hard to show) with $g(z) = a_n (z-z_0) + \ldots$, so $g'(z_0) = a_n \ne 0$.

Comment: Ok. As $\Omega$ is a domain, there exists an $r$>0 such that the open ball centered at $z_0$ with radius $r(i.e B(z_0, r))$ is inside $\Omega$. I can show that $g$ is bounded outside of $B(z_0,r)$. Can you tell how it is bounded inside the ball?

Comment: @user531706: Inside the ball it is bounded because it is continuous, since the limit at $z_0$ exists (and is zero). You need a similar argument to show that the functions defined in the proof in the book are bounded.

Comment: @user31459: This is straightforward. Just solve the equations $f_j(z)=f_j(w)$ for $j=0,1,2$ (with three different cases, depending on whether one or both of them equal one of the $a_j$) to conclude that $z=w$.